# Parsing JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

How do I parse this JSON with PHP:

```
a:6:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:6:{s:4:"uenc";s:148:"aHR0cHM6Ly9lcy5lLW1vc3NhLmV1L2FjY2Vzb3Jpb3MtcGFyYS1jb2NoZS1mdW5kYXMtcGFyYS1hc2llbnRvcy1kZS1jb2NoZS11bml2ZXJzYWwtbWFzdGVyLTU5MDI1MzgxNzA4NTcuaHRtbA,,";....
```

[image]

There are some metadata in there and `json_decode` is not working.

Please advice me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a JSON. It's a serialized array.
You can turn it into an array by calling `$arr = unserialize($yourVarName)`.